# Weather app API with animated radar image

Tags: weather, weather-api

Is there any free API's with a weather radar animation based on longitude and latitude.

I have been looking at https://openweathermap.org as an alternative to absolute free but would like to get som advise and understand which API is the best from a price/performance point of view to create this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can are willing to google translate a Dutch page and wants to create something for the Benelux region you might be interested in [buienradar](https://www.buienradar.nl/overbuienradar/gratis-weerdata)